# How to track traffic of multiple youtube channel through google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

all,

Suppose i am doing advertisement for my website on multiple youtube channel.I am not owner of those channels.Now i want to track whole traffic information (such as session,pageviews etc) by google analytics of each youtube channel where my advertisement is going on.is it possible through google analytics?

that means, how can i  track information of each youtube channel's url through google analytics?

Can i track by google analytics?
Please help me to solve this problem.

Any suggestion is really appreciable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can track YouTube channel using Google Analytics if you are owner of channel.

In any case you can use UTM tags for tracking traffic from YouTube channels.